# login y redirecciones

Tags: php, login

Heredé una pequeña app y le quiero agregar un login. Uso md5 porque el sv tiene instalado php 5.2.

**clases/class_usuario.php**

```
function autorizado($pantalla) {
        require ("../ini/ini.php"); 
                    $bd = new ManejoDB();
                    $bd->conectar_base($connection_stringGHOSP,$userGHOSP,$passGHOSP);
        $query = "select * from quirofano_usuario U,quirofano_roles R,quirofano_roles_pantallas  RP where U.rol_id = R.id and R.id = RP.rol_id and RP.pantalla = '".$pantalla."' and U.dominio = '".$this->dominio."' and U.usuario = '".$this->usuario."'"; 
        //echo  $query;
        if($bd->qBD($query)){
          $salida = array();
          while ($vec = $bd->obtenerReg()){
            $this->id          = $vec['id'];
            $this->dominio     = $vec['dominio'];
            $this->usuario     = $vec['usuario'];
            $this->pass        = $vec['pass'];
            $this->rol_id      = $vec['rol_id'];
            $this->estado      = $vec['estado'];
            $this->insert_user = $vec['insert_user'];
            $this->insert_date = $vec['insert_date'];
            $this->update_user = $vec['update_user'];
            $this->update_date = $vec['update_date'];
            $salida[]= $vec;
          }
          if(count($salida)>0){
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;  
          }              
        }else{
          return false;
        } 
    }

function login($username,$password){
    require ("../ini/ini.php"); 
            $bd = new ManejoDB();
            $bd->conectar_base($connection_stringGHOSP,$userGHOSP,$passGHOSP);
    $query = "select *from quirofano_usuario where usuario = '".$username."' "; 
    if($bd->qBD($query)){
      while ($vec = $bd->obtenerReg()){
        $this->username = $vec['usuario'];
        $this->pass     = $vec['pass'];
      }
    }
    if ($this->pass == md5($password)){
      return true;
    }
    else { return false; }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#login-submit").click(function(){
        if($("#username").val() != "" && $("#password1").val() != ""){
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "login.php",
              data: { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password1").val() }
            }).done(function() {
                    window.location = "index.php";
            });
        }else{
            alert("Por favor llene todos los campos.");
        }
    });
});
```

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                            <input type="button" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Ingresar">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
}else{
    $pagina = 'home_mostrar';
}


include_once("../clases/class_usuario.php");
$usuario = new Usuario();
$usuario->usuario  = $user;
if(!$usuario->autorizado($pagina)){
   $pagina = 'sinPermisos_mostrar';
}


if (strpos($pagina,"_procesar") > 0) {
  if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) {
   include ("../modulos/".$pagina.".php");
  } 
}
else include ("../modulos/index_mostrar.php");
die;
 ?>
```

El problema que tengo es con las redirecciones, no sé como llamar, si está bien el password, para que haga la autorización que está en el index mas abajo. Y ese es el que te redirecciona las páginas. Bueno, después debería iniciar la session y demás.

Otra cosa, en lo que me puedan ayudar con el login para darle más seguridad, se los agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

No logro entender bien tu código te recomendaría que escribieras bien cada documento que estas utilizando. No entiendo la mayor parte de tu codigo y siendo un login siento que es muy desordenado tu código.

Pero lo primero en lo que veo tu error es en el ajax. envias los valores hacia una página aparentemente inexistente.

```
$("#login-submit").click(function(){
    if($("#username").val() != "" && $("#password1").val() != ""){
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "login.php", <-- PAGINA NO EXISTENTE
          data: { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password1").val() }
        }).done(function() {
                window.location = "index.php";
        });
    }else{
        alert("Por favor llene todos los campos.");
    }
});
```

verifica tus conexiones.